# WPF Datatemplate Click Command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Many articles let the `DataTemplate` item which is inside the `DataTemplate` have a `Command`, but I don't want to do so.

I want to add a `Click` `Command` to the `DataTemplate` itself, not to the `Item` inside the `DataTemplate`. Like when I click the `DataTemplate` anywhere it should fire the `Command`, can any body teach me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use an `EventTrigger` in combination with `InvokeCommandAction` like in the following code:

First, add this namespace definition:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and then in your `DataTemplate` definition:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Label Content="{Binding}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.YourClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourControl}}}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Label>
</DataTemplate>
```

For above code to work you need to add the  `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly to your project by going to `Add Reference > Assemblies > Extensions`.

EDIT:
I believe I now understand your question correctly. When you say you want to add the `Command`

> on datatemplate, and I don't want to add command inside datatemplate item

you mean you want to write your code like `<DataTemplate Command="{...}">` or `<DataTemplate Click="...">`.

On the one hand that is not possible because `DataTemplate` does not derive from [`DependencyObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx), and on the other hand that is not even necessary.

If you want the `MouseDown` event to fire when the `ListBoxItem` is clicked, no matter what part of its template is clicked, you can wrap the `DataTemplate`s template in a `Grid` (or `StackPanel` or any other container) and apply the `Interaction.Triggers` to that container:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.YourClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourControl}}}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Label Content="{...}" />
        <Label Content="{...}" />
        <Label Content="{...}" /> 
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now regardless of what label you clicked, the `MouseDown` event will always fire (note that for this to work you need to give the container a background, else the [hit test does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18651665/7571171)).

Comment: First thanks for your answer, in addition, I would like to ask, in addition to this method whether there are other practices, thanks!

Comment: So do you want to be able to use the command in the `DataTemplate` without specifying it there? If so, give me a few minutes, I am already working on an example for that.

Comment: Yes, like your current method, but i want some different method without add Interactivity.dll to keep the project simple.

Comment: @BingFeng as far as I know, there are not _inbuilt_ ways to do that (_inbuilt_ referring to the fact that they are not contained in the .dlls Visual Studio already added as references for you, such as `System.Xaml` or `WindowsBase`), but you could go with [MVVM Lights `EventToCommand`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) even though this does essentially the same for you.

Comment: Thomas thanks for your help, it really helpful for me.  I will try it.